# Can a local government charge a fee to enter a public downtown area during an event?

Tags: united-states

Legally, can a local town or County in the U.S. (Florida) block off access and charge a fee to the citizens to enter a fenced in downtown area during an event?

Comment: What is the nature of the venue to which access is denied when the event is not ongoing?

Comment: Or, to put the question differently, what do you mean by "public"? Government-funded sports arena? Courthouse? City streets?

Comment: Do you live in the area or are you visiting or staying with someone who lives in the area?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

Governments can close or restrict access to public thoroughfares for any number of reasons including emergency response, maintenance, public displays, crowd control etc.

If, for example, the government decided to host a concert on public land they could restrict access to ticket holders. Providing the sale of tickets was not done in an unlawfully discriminatory way, this would be fine.